# Updating TFS field names in more than 1 Team Project Collection

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-reports

I have two Team Project Collections -- DefaultCollection and ArchiveCollection. I need to update the display name for System.ExternalLinkCount from 'ExternalLinkCount' to 'External Link Count'.

This is the command I'm using to accomplish that on both collections:

```
witadmin changefield /collection:http://localhost:8080/tfs/<CollectionName> /n:System.ExternalLinkCount /name:"External Link Count"
```

I get no errors from the command and it tells me that the field is updated. However, after I process the Tfs Warehouse, I see a schema conflict on the field. The DefaultCollection has the updated name, but the ArchiveCollection still has the old name.

That's the part I don't understand. The update is getting made to the same field in both collections, but it isn't updating in the ArchiveCollection.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you double check that the display name was actually changed in the ArchiveCollection? Is it possible that there are other differences between ExternalLinkCount field definitions in these TPCs? Check the output of the listfields command (should be exactly the same for both collections):
'witadmin.exe listfields /collection:<collection url> /n:System.ExternalLinkCount'

Comment: I ran listfields and they appear to be identical.

Comment: I also looked at the fields table in both collections and they match there, too.

Comment: Every collection has its own WIT warehouse adapter job for moving data from TPC database to warehouse DB and also for making schema changes. I guess it is possible that only one of them ran and got blocked because of the schema conflict. I suggest you check the processing status for both collections (using WarehouseControlWebService) and see what was the last time "Work Item Tracking Warehouse Sync" ran, was it after you have made the change to the display name.

Comment: It's almost as if the WIT adapter job for the ArchiveCollection isn't even working.

Comment: If I make the change to only that collection, no schema conflicts ever occur AND the name never updates.

Comment: I have gotten passed the schema conflict! All I did was trigger a rebuild from the Admin Console and then force process the warehouse through the WarehouseControlWebService.